# How to populate a list in python based on another list that contains some of the values from a third list?

Tags: python, list, performance, for-loop

python people.
I have searched many forums for my question without a good enough answer.
I have the following situation:
Imagine that I have a **list1** with user IDs and **list2** with their names. I have also **list3** with some of the user IDs(from **list1**) and I want to create **list4** with the names from **list2**.
I know that I can easily find their names with a for loop searching ID by ID in list3 and lookup the name of the user from list2, but I need speed because I am working with millions of rows.
Here is my code snippet:

```
for userID in list3:
    index = [i for i, x in enumerate(list1) if x == userID]
    list4.append(list2[index])
```

So, my question is if there is a faster approach to that problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let's say `list1, ..., list4` have lengths `n1, ..., n4`. Linear scan for ids in list3 has complexity of O(n1*n3).

Alternative approach is to create a lookup dictionary from list1 and list2. In this case the complexity will be the dictionary creation + lookups, i.e. O(n1) + O(n3).

```
id2name = dict(zip(list1, list2))    
list4 = [id2name[id] for id in list3]
```

In most cases (except very short list3, 0- or 1-length) it will be faster than linear scan

Comment: Marat, thank you very much.

Your suggestion decreased the time a lot. Now the logic is done in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index()` function of list.

```
for userID in list3:
    list4.append(list2[list1.index(userID))
```

I hope this will make your code faster

Comment: it still does linear scan. Best used only on short iterables

Comment: Yes, My first approach was with index() but as  Marat says - still a linear scan which is slow. Thank you anyway :)